# In djago if you extend the user model and you using profile model

Tags: django, django-models

Than how we use below code if we want mobile attribute from  profile model ?

```
user.profile.mobile
```

but profile class has user reference it means it can be possible to access username like this

```
profile.user.username
```

Answer (score 0):

**Define a `related_name` to call the reverse accessor:**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user_name = models.OneToOneField(to= User,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name='profile')
    mobile = models.PositiveIntegerField(null = True,blank = True)
```

> print(request.user.profile.mobile)